# Don't compile all css file into app.css and include some of them manually when needed

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have an Elixir/Phoenix application in which I use brunch and npm. Since all css files are compiled into app.css and I want to not compile them all but only some of them, and include ones that aren't compiled manually on certain pages, I wonder, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a brand new Phoenix 1.2 app, here's how to setup `/css/app.css` to contain all files except `web/static/css/foo.css` and `web/static/css/bar.css`, `/css/foo.css` to contain only `web/static/css/foo.css`, and `/css/bar.css` to contain only `web/static/css/bar.css`:

Modify `brunch-config.js`'s `stylesheets:` object to the following:

```
...
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: {
    "css/app.css": [/^web\/static\/css\//, "!web/static/css/foo.css", "!web/static/css/bar.css"],
    "css/foo.css": "web/static/css/foo.css",
    "css/bar.css": "web/static/css/bar.css"
  },
  order: {
    after: ["web/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
  }
},
...
```

Then, in the views, you can include these files separately like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/foo.css") %>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/bar.css") %>">
```

Comment: thanks. if I have a scss file, can I just include it as a normal css file or do I need to install a dependency first?

Comment: thanks. if I have a scss file, can I just include it as a normal css file or do I need to install a dependency first?

Comment: I want them not to be compiled into app.css, can I do that and how?

Comment: @Johshi just add the paths with a leading `!` (like `!web/static/css/foo.scss`) to the `css/app.css` array, just like I've done for `foo.css` and `bar.css`.

Comment: but what if there're many of them? how to do that for all of them? I don't want it to concatenate them for now at all for the debug purpose.

Comment: You can do `"css/app.css": "web/static/css/app.css",` and then `app.css` will only have `app.css`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I also want to include the rest of them manually but without having to specify them in brunch-config.js, just like I'd do for a static website. If I don't specify them in "joinTo", they won't be available, will they?